# Rails tests showing 0% passed when all pass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

My Rails app passes its test but then says 0% passed. Its a Rails 3 app converted to 3.1.

```
5 tests, 11 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
0% passed
```

If I generate a new Rails 3.1 app it doesnt have this "passed" line.

```
1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Both are running under 1.9.2 p290.

I tried removing test-unit but that did not seem to make a difference and nothing else stands out to me that would cause it.  I guess something is triggering the use of a different test runner.

These are the gems installed for my app:

```
actionmailer (3.1.1)
actionpack (3.1.1)
activemodel (3.1.1)
activerecord (3.1.1)
activeresource (3.1.1)
activesupport (3.1.1)
ansi (1.3.0)
archive-tar-minitar (0.5.2)
arel (2.2.1)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
bootstrap-sass (1.3.0)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.21)
coderay (0.9.8)
coffee-rails (3.1.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.1.2)
columnize (0.3.4)
devise (1.4.7)
devise_rpx_connectable (0.2.2)
enumerated_attribute (0.2.16)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.2.9)
haml (3.1.3)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
jquery-rails (1.0.14)
json (1.6.1)
json_pure (1.6.1)
linecache19 (0.5.12)
mail (2.3.0)
meta_programming (0.2.2)
method_source (0.6.6)
mime-types (1.16)
multi_json (1.0.3)
orm_adapter (0.0.5)
polyglot (0.3.2)
pry (0.9.6.2)
pry-doc (0.3.0)
rack (1.3.4)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rack-webconsole (0.1.2)
rails (3.1.1)
railties (3.1.1)
rake (0.9.2)
rdoc (3.10)
rpx_now (0.6.24)
ruby-debug-base19 (0.11.25)
ruby-debug19 (0.11.6)
ruby_core_source (0.1.5)
ruby_parser (2.0.6)
sass (3.1.10)
sass-rails (3.1.4)
sexp_processor (3.0.7)
slop (2.1.0)
sprockets (2.0.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.4)
test-unit (2.4.0)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
turn (0.8.2)
tzinfo (0.3.30)
uglifier (1.0.3)
warden (1.0.6)
yard (0.7.2)
```

And this is what I get with the default rails new'd app

```
actionmailer (3.1.1)
actionpack (3.1.1)
activemodel (3.1.1)
activerecord (3.1.1)
activeresource (3.1.1)
activesupport (3.1.1)
ansi (1.3.0)
arel (2.2.1)
builder (3.0.0)
bundler (1.0.21)
coffee-rails (3.1.1)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.1.2)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.2.9)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.0)
jquery-rails (1.0.14)
json (1.6.1)
mail (2.3.0)
mime-types (1.16)
multi_json (1.0.3)
polyglot (0.3.2)
rack (1.3.4)
rack-cache (1.1)
rack-mount (0.8.3)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.1)
rails (3.1.1)
railties (3.1.1)
rake (0.9.2)
rdoc (3.10)
sass (3.1.10)
sass-rails (3.1.4)
sprockets (2.0.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.4)
test-unit (2.4.0)
thor (0.14.6)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.10)
turn (0.8.2)
tzinfo (0.3.30)
uglifier (1.0.3)
```

EDIT

I have cut out everything from the app and pushed it to github - https://github.com/kimptoc/zero-percent-bugette
When I just run "rake", I still get 0% passed:

```
$ rake
Loaded suite /Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@p-viadropbox31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started

Finished in 0.000897 seconds.

1 tests, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 pendings, 0 omissions, 0 notifications
0% passed

1114.83 tests/s, 1114.83 assertions/s
Coverage report generated for /Users/kimptoc/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@p-viadropbox31/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader.rb  to    /Users/kimptoc/dev/ruby/fran/zero-percent/coverage. 4 / 4 LOC (100.0%) covered.
```

Comment: Do you've any complete project one can take a look at?

Comment: Hi Oleander - let me see what I can knock up

Comment: Push it to Github when you're done.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using `test-unit` with Rails, then you cannot do anything. I believe it is a bug in `activesupport` gem that comes with Rails. In more detail:

Normally, `test-unit` has a method `add_pass` that increases the count of tests that pass. This is called inside `run(...)` method (`testcase.rb` file). However, `activesupport` hides/overrides this method with its own implementation. It is method `run(...)` inside file `setup_and_teardown.rb` (The full name of method is `ActiveSupport::Testing::SetupAndTeardown::ForClassicTestUnit#run()`.

I have modified this method as follows:

```
    def run(result)
      return if @method_name.to_s == "default_test"

      mocha_counter = retrieve_mocha_counter(result)
      yield(Test::Unit::TestCase::STARTED, name)
      @_result = result

      begin
        begin
          _run_setup_callbacks do
            setup
            __send__(@method_name)
            mocha_verify(mocha_counter) if mocha_counter
          end
        result.add_pass # XXXXXXXXXXXX My Addition to count passed tests XXXXXXXXXX
        rescue Mocha::ExpectationError => e
          add_failure(e.message, e.backtrace)
        rescue Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError => e
          add_failure(e.message, e.backtrace)
        rescue Exception => e
          raise if PASSTHROUGH_EXCEPTIONS.include?(e.class)
          add_error(e)
        ensure
          begin
            teardown
            _run_teardown_callbacks
          rescue Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError => e
            add_failure(e.message, e.backtrace)
          rescue Exception => e
            raise if PASSTHROUGH_EXCEPTIONS.include?(e.class)
            add_error(e)
          end
        end
      ensure
        mocha_teardown if mocha_counter
      end

      result.add_run
      yield(Test::Unit::TestCase::FINISHED, name)
    end
```

I have added `result.add_pass` which was not there, and now percentages should be ok.

**UPDATE**: To help you out integrating this change and test/see for yourself, you can clone a gist that I have created using the following command:

```
git clone git://gist.github.com/1324512.git gist-1324512
```

This will create a file with name : `active_support_test_unit_pass_count.rb`

Move that to your `test` folder where `test_helper.rb` file is and require it in your `test_helper.rb` file, exactly before the definition of the `ActiveSupport::TestCase` class:

```
require 'active_support_test_unit_pass_count'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase

....
```

Then run your tests and see the percentage result. To me...it worked ok.

Comment: Thanks - sounds good, although it doesnt seem to have helped... trying a few tweaks to see if I can get it going but no joy - https://github.com/kimptoc/zero-percent-bugette

Comment: @ChrisKimpton My friend, I should have said **exactly** _before the definition of the_ `ActiveSupport::TestCase` class. Move the line `require 'active_support_test_unit_pass_count'` **exactly** before. I cloned your repository. I saw that it didn't work (as you said), then moved the line exactly before the definition of the class, and it ran, this time, with success. Try for yourself and you will see. (I have also edited my answer to reflect thi)

Comment: That did it - thanks.  Seems like a Rails/activesupport bugette - will raise it on the rails issue list.

Comment: FWIW - Oh- it seems its been raised already - https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/2472

Comment: Thanks! Also, if you're having problems including the file use this line: require File.expand_path('../../test/active_support_test_unit_pass_count', __FILE__)

Answer (score 2):

I ran across this on an old Rails 3.2.22 app. I found an easier solution than above (above gave me other errors as it makes assumptions about versions etc).
I added `test-unit-rails` gem to my gemfile, for me I had to lock it to version `1.0.4` as it supported the version of test-unit I was previously using.

In my `test_helper.rb` file I added:

```
require "test/unit/active_support"
require 'active_support'
```

[Here's](https://test-unit.github.io/#test-unit) the docs I found it from. Specifically, it's an active-support plugin for test-unit.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing test unit and installing mini-test. In your Gemfile:

```
gem "minitest"
```

Comment: Thanks - but no difference, still says 0% passed, yet all green.  I thought minitest was in 1.9, but I guess there is more to is...

Comment: Have you tried it without ruby-debug19 in your gemfile? Just stabbing in the dark, at this point.

Comment: LOL - same here, just tried uninstalling that too-  no better :(  .

Comment: minitest solved this for me, but only after I removed test-unit.

Comment: For me the problem was that I was using guard-test instead of guard-minitest. The guard-test gem was dependent on the old test-unit. Along these lines, you might just want to check your Gemfile.lock to see if Bundler is requiring a different version of test/unit because of one of your gems. Another way to test your gem dependencies is to run this: `ruby -rbundler/setup -rtest/unit -e "puts ::Test::Unit::TEST_UNIT_IMPLEMENTATION"`. If it says `uninitialized constant Test::Unit::TEST_UNIT_IMPLEMENTATION (NameError)`, then you're not using minitest.